# Not able to see Screen Name data (firebase_screen_name or firebase_screen) on the result of the BigQuery

Tags: events, google-bigquery, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I was trying to use the Screen name data in order to perform some queries on BigQuery related to Firebase Events Analytics.
In order to do that, I've tried to check that the data exists on the result of the BigQuery.

I've added this into app, in order to manually log the screen name and screen class:

```
Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView,
                   parameters: [AnalyticsParameterScreenName: "name_xyz",
                                AnalyticsParameterScreenClass: "XActivity"])
```

I've done some query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `project.analytics_000000000.events_20220608`
WHERE 
  event_name = 'screen_view' 
  and platform = 'ANDROID'  
  and (
    event_params[OFFSET(0)].key = "firebase_screen_class" 
    and event_params[OFFSET(0)].value.string_value = "XActivity"
  )
```

One result entry example:

```
{
    "event_date": "20220608",
    "event_timestamp": "123456",
    "event_name": "screen_view",
    "event_params": [{
            "key": "firebase_screen_class",
            "value": {
                "string_value": "XActivity",
                "int_value": null,
                "float_value": null,
                "double_value": null
            }
        }, {
            "key": "engaged_session_event",
            "value": {
                "string_value": null,
                "int_value": "?",
                "float_value": null,
                "double_value": null
            }
        }, {
            "key": "firebase_previous_id",
            "value": {
                "string_value": null,
                "int_value": "?",
                "float_value": null,
                "double_value": null
            }
        }, {
            "key": "firebase_event_origin",
            "value": {
                "string_value": "?",
                "int_value": null,
                "float_value": null,
                "double_value": null
            }
        }, {
            "key": "ga_session_id",
            "value": {
                "string_value": null,
                "int_value": "?",
                "float_value": null,
                "double_value": null
            }
        }, {
            "key": "firebase_previous_class",
            "value": {
                "string_value": "YActivity",
                "int_value": null,
                "float_value": null,
                "double_value": null
            }
        }, {
            "key": "firebase_screen_id",
            "value": {
                "string_value": null,
                "int_value": "?",
                "float_value": null,
                "double_value": null
            }
        }, {
            "key": "ga_session_number",
            "value": {
                "string_value": null,
                "int_value": "?",
                "float_value": null,
                "double_value": null
            }
        }
    ],
    "event_previous_timestamp": "?",
    "event_value_in_usd": "?",
    "event_bundle_sequence_id": "?",
    "event_server_timestamp_offset": "?",
    "user_id": null,
    "user_pseudo_id": "?",
    "privacy_info": {
        "analytics_storage": "?",
        "ads_storage": "?",
        "uses_transient_token": "?"
    },
    "user_properties": [{
            "key": "ga_session_number",
            "value": {
                "string_value": null,
                "int_value": "?",
                "float_value": null,
                "double_value": null,
                "set_timestamp_micros": "?"
            }
        }, {
            "key": "first_open_time",
            "value": {
                "string_value": null,
                "int_value": "?",
                "float_value": null,
                "double_value": null,
                "set_timestamp_micros": "?"
            }
        }, {
            "key": "ga_session_id",
            "value": {
                "string_value": null,
                "int_value": "?",
                "float_value": null,
                "double_value": null,
                "set_timestamp_micros": "?"
            }
        }
    ],
    "user_first_touch_timestamp": "?",
    "user_ltv": "?",
    "device": {
        "category": "?",
        "mobile_brand_name": "?",
        "mobile_model_name": "?",
        "mobile_marketing_name": "?",
        "mobile_os_hardware_model": "?",
        "operating_system": "?",
        "operating_system_version": "?",
        "vendor_id": "?",
        "advertising_id": "?",
        "language": "?",
        "is_limited_ad_tracking": "?",
        "time_zone_offset_seconds": "?",
        "browser": "?",
        "browser_version": "?",
        "web_info": "?"
    },
    "geo": {
        "continent": "?",
        "country": "?",
        "region": "?",
        "city": "?",
        "sub_continent": "?",
        "metro": "?"
    },
    "app_info": {
        "id": "?",
        "version": "?",
        "install_store": "?",
        "firebase_app_id": "?",
        "install_source": "?"
    },
    "traffic_source": {
        "name": "?",
        "medium": "?",
        "source": "?"
    },
    "stream_id": "?",
    "platform": "?",
    "event_dimensions": "?",
    "ecommerce": "?",
    "items": []
}
```

So no data like below:

```
"event_params": [{
            "key": "firebase_screen_name",
            "value": {
                "string_value": "name_xyz",
                "int_value": null,
                "float_value": null,
                "double_value": null
            }
        }
```

or

```
"event_params": [{
            "key": "firebase_screen",
            "value": {
                "string_value": "name_xyz",
                "int_value": null,
                "float_value": null,
                "double_value": null
            }
        }
```

Could someone help, what am I missing?
As I can see the Screen names on Google Analytics console, somehow Google is getting this info from somewhere.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need
`SELECT  event_param.value.string_value AS ScreenName
FROM    `analytics_xxxx.events_*`, UNNEST (event_params) AS event_param
WHERE   event_name = 'screen_view'
`

Answer (score 0):

You don't know the order of the screen key in the event_params array. So instead of accessing offset(0), it's better to search for it in the array.

```
SELECT *
FROM `project.analytics_000000000.events_20220608`
WHERE 
  event_name = 'screen_view' 
  and platform = 'ANDROID'  
  and (
    select count(*) 
    from unnest(event_params) as param 
    where key = "firebase_screen_class" 
        and value.string_value = "XActivity"
  ) > 0
```